automate remediation of a headless RHEL 8.9 AMI with exclusions
I'm trying to automate remediation of a headless RHEL 8.9 AMI.  What is the best way to remediate ALL but a specific subset of the STIG requirements?  I.e., there are 4 STIG requirements that we know will break our build and we have exceptions for them.  In other words, how can I remediate ALL STIG requirements except a specific subset?  Is this possible?
I've considered using sudo oscap xccdf eval --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_stig --results scan-xccdf-results.xml /usr/share/xml/scap/ssg/content/ssg-rhel8-ds.xml to generate the XCCDF file in XML format, but then scripting the XML modifications via shell or python is gross.
I've also considered using sudo oscap xccdf generate fix --template urn:xccdf:fix:script:sh --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_stig --output test-remediation-script.sh /usr/share/xml/scap/ssg/content/ssg-rhel8-ds.xml to generate a remediation script, then scripting the modifications this way as well.
But I can't be the first person to do this.  Can I?  Someone has to have done this before, without using the UI?

You can use a tailoring file, which basically is a customization of a profile where you can include or remove rules.
Here are some references on how to create a tailoring file:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3641661
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/system_design_guide/scanning_the_system_for_security_compliance_and_vulnerabilities#customizing-a-security-profile-with-scap-workbench_scanning-the-system-with-a-customized-profile-using-scap-workbench


Thank you, Marcus!  I was able to find out that using a tailoring file was the key.  As feedback to the community, I built my script thusly:
`autotailor --unselect xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_mount_option_var_tmp_noexec --output stig-tailoring.xml --new-profile-id custom /usr/share/xml/scap/ssg/content/ssg-rhel8-ds.xml stig
sudo oscap xccdf generate fix --template urn:xccdf:fix:script:sh --profile custom --tailoring-file stig-tailoring.xml --output test-remediation-script.sh /usr/share/xml/scap/ssg/content/ssg-rhel8-ds.xml
sudo ./test-remediation-script.sh &> remediation.out`

Great. Perhaps you would also be interested on https://github.com/ComplianceAsCode/content. We also have some scripts there and any contribution is always welcome.
